# Syntax error : identifier 'String'

Tags: c++-cli

We received this piece of code for an assignment, and after spending a lot of time fixing the problems within, I ended up with a `syntax error : identifier 'String'`. Everywhere I look on the web, people are using `std::string`, but this is not what the code is referring to since the function is called from a C# project using a `String` object.

Here is the declaration :

```
int findWindow(String ^CaptionText,IntPtr ^%phWnd,
               int %left,int %top,int %right,int %bottom);
```

And I have no idea how to fix that one. There are other errors such as

```
error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
...
error C2065: 'IntPtr' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'String' : undeclared identifier
...
```

etc.

Any help appreciated.

Should I mention that those errors have nothing to do with the assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `System::String` and `System::IntPtr` or write `using namespace System;`

Comment: thanks. We have so little support from that teacher... and most of the class never coded with VC++ (not to mention creating DLL mixing C++ and C#) before.